# Проблема поиска текстовых значений в hex

Tags: графика, textview, hex

Выгрузил прошивку приборной панели. Контроллер `motorolla mc68hc912dg128`.
В файле прошивки не нашел ни текстовых, ни графических сигнатур.

Подскажите  на каком языке был написан исходник и как найти  блок отвечающий за текст или графику?

В прошивке вшито несколько языков, менял английский и немецкий и сливал обратно. Hex редактором сравнивал коды. Отличий много закономерностей не увидел. Помогите разобраться, возможно ли декомпилировать такой код, или просто привести в нормальный вид чтоб было понятно. Подозреваю что текст выводится на `lcd(100х64 пикс, монохром)` экран попиксельно и при смене языка меняется графическая интерпретация.

[Код](https://fex.net/uk/s/ms0mzx3)

То что ищу в коде вчастности надпись `"fuel level low"` Помогите советом буду благодарен за любую информацию.

[image: Надпись]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрев в бинарный файл, легко найти, что картинка начинается где то в районе 0x3488. Одна строка - 12 байт. Дальше дело техники

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  FILE* f = fopen("Source.bin", "r");
  int p = 0x347E; // где начинается картинка. Возможно, она начинается на пару строк выше
  int counter = 1; // смещение в битах
  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) printf(" "); // напечатаем несколько пробелов, что бы компенсировать смещение в бите
  int line_size = 12*8; // размер строки
  fseek(f, p, SEEK_SET); // переедем сразу куда нужно
  for (int i = 0; i < 640; i++) { // опытным путем установлено, что там 640 байт на картинку
    int c = fgetc(f); // читаем по байту
    if (c == -1) break; // ой, конец неожиданный файла, выходим
    for (int j = 0; j<8;j++) {
      int z = c & (1<<(7-j)); // извлекаем бит
      if (z == 0) printf(" "); else printf("#"); // и печатаем его
      counter++; // счетчик точек в строке
      if (counter == line_size) {printf("\n"); counter = 0;} // новая строка
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Как увидеть картинку? очень просто. Распечатываем в консоль файл в виде битов - 1 и 0. А дальше смотрим на оригинальную картинку, выписываем последовательность нулей и единиц  и ищем.

```
                   ##### #   # ##### #           #     ##### #   # ##### #
                   #     #   # #     #           #     #     #   # #     #
                   #     #   # #     #           #     #     #   # #     #
                   ####  #   # ####  #           #     ####  #   # ####  #
                   #     #   # #     #           #     #     #   # #     #
                   #     #   # #     #           #     #      # #  #     #
                   #      ###  ##### #####       ##### #####   #   ##### #####




                                        #      ###  #   #
                                        #     #   # #   #
                                        #     #   # # # #
                                        #     #   # # # #
                                        #     #   # # # #
                                        #     #   # # # #
                                        #####  ###   # #






                                        ##############    #
                                       ################   ##
                                       ##            ##    ##
                                       ##            ##     ###
                                       ##            ##      ###
                                       ##            ##       ##
                                       ##            ##       ###
                                       ##            ##       ###
                                       ##            ##       ###
                                       ##            ##       ##
                                       ##            ##       ##
                                       #################      ##
                                       ##################     ##
                                       ################ ##    ##
                                       ################  ##   ##
                                       ################  ##   ##
                                       ################  ##    ##
                                       ################  ##    ##
                                       ################  ##    ##
                                       ################  ##     ##
                                       ################  ##     ##
                                       ################  ##     ##
                                       ################  ##     ##
                                       ################  ##     ##
                                       ################   ##   ##
                                       ################    #####
                                       ################     ###
                                       ################
                                       ################
                                      ##################
```

Comment: Одна строка 12 байт это статическое значение или плавающее для первой строки картинок?  И о последовательности нуля и еденицы понял но не не совсем. Не понял как потом производить поиск.В любом случае благодарность,начало положено.

Comment: 12 байт - это длина строки. это 96 точек (что близко к Вашему 100). О последовательности - я посмотрел на картинку и выписал где то такое "##### #   # ##### #" - это верхушка букв FUEL. Потом кодом выше просто распечатал весь весь файл побитно в таком же виде. Теперь осталось обычным поиском в текстовом редакторе найти эту последовательность. Найденную позицию поделить на 8 (бит в байте и уже нашли). А дальше просто игра позицией и смещением.

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное! +100 Вам в карму. Несколько дней не мог визуализировать.

Comment: можно просто галочку напротив ответа поставить